# Problem with new environment and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, environments

I want to define a new environment for making graph easier in Tikz :

```
  \newenvironment{tikzc}[7]
  {\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmini}{#2};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxi}{#3};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymini}{#4};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymaxi}{#5};
  \begin{axis}[xmin=\xmini,xmax=\xmaxi,ymin=\ymini,ymax=\ymaxi,axis lines=center, clip = false, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
  \node[scale=0.1] (y) at (\xmini,\ymaxi){};
  \node[scale=0.1] (x) at (\xmaxi,\ymini){};
  \node[left= 0.09cm of x,scale=0.5] (xlabel) at ([yshift=-0.12cm]$(x)$){#6};
  \node[left= 0.04cm of y,scale=0.5] (ylabel) at ([yshift=-0.11cm]$(y)$){#7};
  }
  {\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  }
```

But I get

> "File ended while scanning use of \path" why ?

Comment: you only showed the definition not the use where there is an error , please edit the example so people can run it and see the error. but do you _really_ want an environment with 7 arguments that is going to be horrible to use and check that the syntax is correct.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example code, from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`. It might be possible for someone to determine the problem from your environment definition, but it's likely that we also need to know what packages you load and what seven arguments are needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro works. So you probably are feeding it with something that triggers the error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\newenvironment{tikzc}[7]
  {\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmini}{#2};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmaxi}{#3};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymini}{#4};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymaxi}{#5};
  \begin{axis}[xmin=\xmini,xmax=\xmaxi,ymin=\ymini,ymax=\ymaxi,axis lines=center, clip = false, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
  \node[scale=0.1] (y) at (\xmini,\ymaxi){};
  \node[scale=0.1] (x) at (\xmaxi,\ymini){};
  \node[left= 0.09cm of x,scale=0.5] (xlabel) at ([yshift=-0.12cm]$(x)$){#6};
  \node[left= 0.04cm of y,scale=0.5] (ylabel) at ([yshift=-0.11cm]$(y)$){#7};
  }
  {\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzc}{1}{0}{10}{0}{5}{$x$}{$y$}
        \addplot[very thick,red,domain=0:5] {0.04*x^2};
\end{tikzc}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Move the `\begin{document}` after the `\newenvironment...`.

Comment: Thank a lot ! I didn't know that i need to put newenvironment after the begin document, is there any way to put it before ?

Comment: @Oka You don't have to. Actually it would be even cleaner if you/I moved the `\begin{document}` after the `\newenvironment...`. I just double-checked that this also works.